# Test Unitarios java

Tags: java

Estoy un ejercicio de clase para realizar test,

El código del test me lo han dado, pero el otro lo he tenido que realizar yo.
consiste básicamente en
codificar los siguientes 5 métodos/funciones que permiten calcular el oro que recibirá un
personaje de un videojuego a partir de un conjunto de logros que haya completad:

Este es el código realizado

```
    public class PAC1Ex2 {
    
        private static final double LEVEL_MULTIPLIER = 4.5;
        private static final double[] DIFFICULTY_MULTIPLIER = {1.0, 1.5, 2.5, 5.0};
        private static final int GOLD_BASE = 100;
        public static String ERR_LEVEL = "[ERROR] Invalid level";
    
        public static boolean isValidLevel(byte level) {
    
            return level >= 1 && level <= 99;
        }
    
        public static boolean isValidDifficulty(byte difficulty) {
            return difficulty >= 1 && difficulty <= 4;
        }
    
        public static double getMultiplierByDifficulty(byte difficulty) {
            if (isValidDifficulty(difficulty)) {
                return DIFFICULTY_MULTIPLIER[difficulty - 1];
            } else {
                // Si la dificultad no es válida, devuelve -1 para indicar un error.
                return -1;
            }
        }
    
        public static double calculateGold(byte level, byte difficulty) {
            if (!isValidLevel(level) || !isValidDifficulty(difficulty)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid level or difficulty");
                return -1; // o puedes manejarlo de otra manera, como lanzar una excepción
            }
    
            
            double multiplier = getMultiplierByDifficulty(difficulty);
            double levelMultiplier = level * LEVEL_MULTIPLIER;
    
            return GOLD_BASE + levelMultiplier * multiplier;
        }
    
        public static void getAchievementsGold(byte level, byte[] difficulties) {
            int invalidDifficulties = 1;
            double totalGold = 1;
            int validAchievements = 1;
    
            for (byte difficulty : difficulties) {
                if (isValidDifficulty(difficulty)) {
                    double gold = calculateGold(level, difficulty);
                    if (gold != -1) {
                        totalGold += gold;
                        validAchievements++;
                    } else {
                        invalidDifficulties++;
                    }
                } else {
                    invalidDifficulties++;
                }
            }
    
            System.out.println("You have obtained a total of " + totalGold + " gold from " + validAchievements + " achievements.");
            System.out.println(invalidDifficulties + " achievements with invalid difficulties have been detected.");
        }
    }
Y este es el codigo del test

public class PAC1Ex2Test {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream outContent;
    private final PrintStream originalOut = System.out;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUpStreams() {
        outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void restoreStreams() {
        System.setOut(originalOut);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidLevel() {
        assertFalse(PAC1Ex2.isValidLevel((byte) 0));
        assertFalse(PAC1Ex2.isValidLevel((byte) 100));
        assertFalse(PAC1Ex2.isValidLevel((byte) -1));
        assertTrue(PAC1Ex2.isValidLevel((byte) 50));
        assertTrue(PAC1Ex2.isValidLevel((byte) 99));
        assertTrue(PAC1Ex2.isValidLevel((byte) 1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidDifficulty() {
        assertFalse(PAC1Ex2.isValidDifficulty((byte) 0));
        assertFalse(PAC1Ex2.isValidDifficulty((byte) 5));
        assertFalse(PAC1Ex2.isValidDifficulty((byte) -1));
        assertTrue(PAC1Ex2.isValidDifficulty((byte) 1));
        assertTrue(PAC1Ex2.isValidDifficulty((byte) 4));
        assertTrue(PAC1Ex2.isValidDifficulty((byte) 2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMultiplierByDifficulty() {
        assertEquals(1.0, PAC1Ex2.getMultiplierByDifficulty((byte) 1));
        assertEquals(1.5, PAC1Ex2.getMultiplierByDifficulty((byte) 2));
        assertEquals(2.5, PAC1Ex2.getMultiplierByDifficulty((byte) 3));
        assertEquals(5.0, PAC1Ex2.getMultiplierByDifficulty((byte) 4));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalculateGold() {
        assertEquals(104.5, PAC1Ex2.calculateGold((byte) 1, (byte) 1));
        assertEquals(235.0, PAC1Ex2.calculateGold((byte) 30, (byte) 1));
        assertEquals(437.5, PAC1Ex2.calculateGold((byte) 50, (byte) 2));
        assertEquals(943.75, PAC1Ex2.calculateGold((byte) 75, (byte) 3));
        assertEquals(1900.0, PAC1Ex2.calculateGold((byte) 80, (byte) 4));
        assertEquals(2327.5, PAC1Ex2.calculateGold((byte) 99, (byte) 4));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAchievementsGold() {
        PAC1Ex2.getAchievementsGold((byte) 0, new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
        assertEquals(PAC1Ex2.ERR_LEVEL + System.lineSeparator(), outContent.toString());

        outContent.reset();

        PAC1Ex2.getAchievementsGold((byte) 1, new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
        assertEquals("You have obtained a total of 445.0 gold from 4 achievements." + System.lineSeparator() + "0 achievements with invalid difficulties have been detected." + System.lineSeparator(), outContent.toString());

        outContent.reset();

        PAC1Ex2.getAchievementsGold((byte) 30, new byte[]{4, 4, 3, 4});
        assertEquals("You have obtained a total of 2762.5 gold from 4 achievements." + System.lineSeparator() + "0 achievements with invalid difficulties have been detected." + System.lineSeparator(), outContent.toString());

        outContent.reset();

        PAC1Ex2.getAchievementsGold((byte) 50, new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
        assertEquals("You have obtained a total of 2650.0 gold from 4 achievements." + System.lineSeparator() + "1 achievements with invalid difficulties have been detected." + System.lineSeparator(), outContent.toString());

        outContent.reset();

        PAC1Ex2.getAchievementsGold((byte) 75, new byte[]{1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3});
        assertEquals("You have obtained a total of 8325.0 gold from 9 achievements." + System.lineSeparator() + "0 achievements with invalid difficulties have been detected." + System.lineSeparator(), outContent.toString());

        outContent.reset();

        PAC1Ex2.getAchievementsGold((byte) 99, new byte[]{1, 1, 3, -1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1, 6, 2, 3, 8});
        assertEquals("You have obtained a total of 10701.0 gold from 9 achievements." + System.lineSeparator() + "4 achievements with invalid difficulties have been detected." + System.lineSeparator(), outContent.toString());
    }

}
```

Cuando le doy a run da error y me sale lo siguiente
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
Invalid level or difficulty
Invalid level or difficulty
Invalid level or difficulty
Invalid level or difficulty
You have obtained a total of 1.0 gold from 1 achievements.
5 achievements with invalid difficulties have been detected.

Comment: Solucionado  me faltaba meter public static String ERR_LEVEL = "[ERROR] Invalid level"; aqui:
public static void getAchievementsGold(byte level, byte[] difficulties) {
        int invalidDifficulties = 0;
        double totalGold = 0;
        int validAchievements = 0;
        if (!isValidLevel(level)) {
            System.out.println(ERR_LEVEL);
            return;
        }